# VB To Allow Filtering When Protecting Worksheet

Tags: excel, vb.net, blueprism

I have a Blueprism object which will protect a worksheet but leave a range of cells unprotected.
I want to be able to filter this worksheet. The below code will add filters but you cannot select the drop down. Note range and handle are variables being passed in.

```
GetInstance(handle).Range(range).Locked = False
GetInstance(handle).Range(range).EnableAutoFilter 
GetInstance(handle).ActiveSheet.Protect
```

Comment: You need to allow Auto Filtering `GetInstance(handle).ActiveSheet.Protect AllowFiltering:=True` should do it

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad So I had tried that. With Code GetInstance(handle).Range(range).Locked = False
GetInstance(handle).ActiveSheet.Protect AllowFiltering:=True I am now getting error:
Description: Compiler error at line 2: Method arguments must be enclosed in parentheses.

Comment: As far as I know Blueprism doesn't like spaces in Excel code segments

Comment: @Eoin2211 the error you are getting suggests that you need to enclose the method arguments in brackets so that it reads as `GetInstance(handle).ActiveSheet.Protect(AllowFiltering:=True)`

Comment: @Dave That is producing the error Public member 'EnableAutoFilter' on type 'Range' not found.